# Don's NDEF library and bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, spi

I am trying to connect my Android smartphone with my Arduino Uno by sending a NDEF message to my phone.
I know that the MIME type for bluetooth is application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob but in my PN532 library I don't know what's the right prefix.

You can see prefixes here : https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532/blob/master/PN532/PN532.h#L66

Thank you